# Deploy Multiple Laravel Apps with a Single Domain

Tags: php, laravel, apache, centos

I have two Laravel applications with one domain. Let say the domain is `mydomain.com`.

I want those two applications can be accessed via the following urls:

```
mydomain.com/firstapp
mydomain.com/secondapp
```

To realize this, this is what I have done.

1. configured Apache so that the starting directory is `/var/www/html/`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"
    ServerName mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

2. Then I put the first app source code in the `/var/www/html/firstapp` directory, and the second app in the `/var/html/secondapp` directory.

The directory structure became like this:

```
var
└── www
    └── html
        ├── firstapp
        │   ├── app
        │   ├── bootstrap
        │   ├── config
        │   ├── database
        │   ├── ...
        │   ├── index.php
        │   └── .htaccess
        └── secondapp
            ├── app
            ├── bootstrap
            ├── config
            ├── database
            ├── ...
            ├── index.php
            └── .htaccess
```

3. Finally, I moved the `index.php` and `.htaccess` from the corresponding public folder in the root directory of each Laravel app and modified the corresponding path in those `index.php` files.

So far, it is working as I expected, but I am worried about the security.

Can anyone explain to me the right way to do it.

Note: I am using Centos 7 in the server.

Comment: I would suggest to create sub domains. If you don't want to go for that. Then next you can do, to paste the first project on public_html root which will be accessable like mydomain.com and for second create another folder and paste the project code there. which will be mydomain.com/second etc...

Comment: @AkhtarMunir Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, because of some reasons, using subdomains is not an option for me this time.
Something that bothers me is that, is it okay to put index.php in the root directory of a Laravel project?

Comment: yeah it's okay, it's not an issue unless you have SSL installed on your server. But a really proper way is to put index and htaccess file inside laravel public folder and put all your project files ao another folder and link through index.